# How Upcasting preserve derived classes's Properties?

Tags: c#, casting, boxing

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student = new Student()
            {
                ID = 12,
                Name = "Manu",
                LastName = "Shekar"
            };

            Iregister x = student;
            Student newstudent = x as Student;

           //Console.WriteLine(x.LastName); //Uncommenting this shows compilation error
            Console.WriteLine(newstudent.LastName); //This Show "Shekar"
            Console.ReadKey();

        }


    class Student : Iregister
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }

    }
    interface Iregister
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
        String Name { get; set; }


    }
```

I wonder how the `newstudent.LastName` gets the correct value since it is casted from `Iregister` which doesn't have `LastName` property? 
How the value "Shekar" is passed from `student.LastName` to `newstudent.LastName`. Did `x` stores it somewhere in between? Pardon me if i miss something basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a single *object*, and assign a reference to it in the variable `student`.

You then create a second *reference* to the same object and assign that to `x`. Both `x` and `student` are referring to the same object, but the type of the `x` variable means that only the members defined on `IRegister` are available.

You then create a third reference to the same object and assign that to `newstudent`. Since `newstudent` is of type `Student`, you can access all of the member of `Student` from that reference.

Not that the variables just store references. It's the *object* that stores its own actual data, and that object remained unchanged throughout the process.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder how the newstudent.LastName gets the correct value since it
>   is casted from Iregister which doesn't have LastName property?

The truth is that `x` is a type `Iregister` but it's *pointing* to a `Student` object hence once casted you're able to access the `Student` fields.

Answer (score 1):

When using `x` directly, the compiler allows you to choose only the members defined on `IRegister` type, because `x` is of that type. Once you cast `x` to `Student`, the compiler allows you to use any member of `Student`, since the `newstudent` variable is of type `Student`.

Comment: How the value "Shekar" is passed from `student.LastName` to `newstudent.LastName`. Did `x` stores it somewhere in between?

Comment: `x` is only a variable. For the whole time you have only one object in memory. A variable only points to that object.

Comment: @NithinChandran: Imagine if I put the Mona Lisa in a security locker, and I give three different people a key to the locker. Three people (variables) have **access** to the locker and can look at the Mona Lisa (object) when they want to, but **only one Mona Lisa painting (object) exists**. Your variables each have a reference (locker key), but all of their references point to the same object in memory (all of their keys are used for the same locker)

Comment: @Flater Excellent analogy. I understood the concept from all the answers

Comment: @NithinChandran: If I had had more space to type, I would've added an example where if one of the three people draws a mustache on the painting, then all three people will see a mustachiod Mona Lisa for that point on :) But happy to see the explanation helped! :)

Comment: @Flater You helped me again man. If stackoverflow had a `follow him` button i wouldn't have hesitate to click on it

Answer (score 1):

> How Interface stores inherited class's Property

Interfaces do not **store** values. They only ensure the availability of certain properties and methods in the classes that implement the interface.

> I wonder how the `newstudent.LastName` gets the correct value since it is casted from `Iregister` which doesn't have `LastName` property?

Downcasting an object does not change the object's type, it only changes the type of the **variable** that you're using.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    String Name { get; }
}

public class BaseType : IMyInterface
{
    public virtual String Name
    {
        get { return "Base Name"; }
    }
}

public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    public override String Name
    {
        get { return "Derived Name"; }
    }
}
```

I then tested the following commands in the C# Interactive window:

```
var derived = new DerivedType();

IMyInterface derivedAsInterface = derived;
BaseType derivedAsBaseType = derived;

derived.Name                //returns "Derived Name"
derivedAsInterface.Name     //returns "Derived Name"
derivedAsBaseType.Name      //returns "Derived Name"
```

As you can see, whenever you ask for the `Name` property, the object still behaves as a `DerivedType`, because that is what the object is.

This is because classes are inherently **reference types**. This does work differently for **value types** (e.g. `float` and `int`), but that has to do with the inherent differences between value and reference types.
If you want to know why, read up on [the difference between value and reference types in C#](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)

---

If you think about it, your assumption does not make sense. In my code example, I have three separate variables: `derived`, `derivedAsInterface`, `derivedAsBaseType`. These all point to the **same** object in memory.

This logically means that the same object must be compatible with all three variables, otherwise it would be impossible to use all these variables when you want to.

- If the object was changed into an object of type `IMyInterface`, then my variables `derivedAsBaseType` and `derived` would no longer function correctly.
- If the object was changed into an object of type `BaseType`, then my variable `derived` would no longer function correctly.
- The only remaining explanation is that my object has always kept its original type (`DerivedType`), since that is the only way how it can maintain compatibility with all three variables.

*If you do not understand why they refer to the same object in memory, you should read up on [the difference between value and reference types in C#](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm). This topic is much too broad for an answer on StackOverflow.*