# Why an object saves properties when upcasted

Tags: c#, upcasting

I've got a simple question concerning upcasting in c#. For example I have two interfaces:

```
interface IUSer
{
    string UserName { get; set; }
}

interface IAdmin: IUSer
{
    string Password { get; set; }
}
```

...and a class implementing IAdmin interface:

```
class Admin : IAdmin
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

When I create an object of type Admin and try to upcast it to IUser, technically I can then only access UserName user.UserName:

```
var admin = new Admin() { UserName = "Arthur", Password = "hello" };
var user = (IUSer)admin;
Console.WriteLine( user.UserName );
```

...but If I cycle through this object's properties using Reflection, like that:

```
    private static void Outputter(IUSer user)
    {
        foreach (var prop in user.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name +  " " + prop.GetValue(admin));
        }
    }
```

...I can also see Password property. The question is - why it is saved when upcasted?

Comment: Would you like the CLR to delete them? that would make life difficult for everyone else in the world dont you think? the asnwer is so you can downcast again

Comment: But what If I need to send an upcasted object through some kind of a transport protocol to a server or something for example, will Password property from this example be sent also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Upcasting preserve derived classes's Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115856/how-upcasting-preserve-derived-classess-properties)

Comment: See @daisyShipton answer, nailed it

Comment: also *But what If I need to send an upcasted object through some kind of a transport protocol to a server* is a completely different question really

Comment: @TheGeneral I have seen such case, if we have the same Type defined on remote server, we can easily cast object back to original type.

Comment: @amit agreed, however this is more a serialization problem more than a casting one

Comment: @ArthurBardakov what case you are saying, to reproduce such case and understand it's behaviour, you are not even required to implement interface hierarchy (as you shown in question), you just need to use non-generic collection. I bet you were doing this all the time.

Comment: @TheGeneral yes, that is true!

Comment: @amit Thanks, got it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The question is - why it is saved when upcasted?

Because casting doesn't change the *object* at all. It just changes how you're *viewing* the object.

Think of it like being a person. You may have different ways that people can view you:

- A colleague
- A manager
- A family member
- A friend

They only "see" certain aspects of you, but that doesn't change who you are.

Likewise a simple reference conversion doesn't change the object. If you call `user.GetType()` it will still report the *actual* type of the object. It's just that when you view the object through a particular lens (whether that's an interface or a base class) you only see the members that lens shows you.

(Note that a cast that calls a user-defined conversion, e.g. casting from `XElement` to `string`, is entirely different. That returns a reference to a new object, rather than just regarding the existing object in a different way.)

If you only want to see the `IUser` properties, use `typeof(IUser).GetProperties()` instead of calling `GetType()` first:

```
private static void Outputter(IUser user)
{
    foreach (var prop in typeof(IUser).GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {prop.GetValue(user)}");
    }
}
```

Although I'm not sure it's particularly useful to do that with reflection in most cases.

Comment: Great analogy!!

Comment: Totally agree!! Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 1):

when you cast the object of any type to their base type, you are just holding that object with they type of base.

object doesn't loos its properties by that.

If you see a simplest example : **Use of non generic collection**

when you add some object (let's say of `Admin` class) in `ArrayList`, you are actually converting that object into type `object` (Boxing) and then store it arraylist.  So it is ultimate example of up-casting! How?

> The object type is an alias for Object in the .NET Framework. In the unified type system of C#, all types, predefined and user-defined, reference types and value types, inherit directly or indirectly from Object.

[Full Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/object)

Now `object` type doesn't hold properties like `userName` `password`.
So when you try to access those property from the object you get directly from arraylist, you will not able to do so. Because current you are dealing with the type `object` and you will get access only those properties or members which is supported by `object` type (but here you are not getting access, still those properties are there). In addition as note in other answer `GetType()` method will surely return it's original type too.

But when you get that original object back from array list by casting it back to `Admin` type (Unboxing) , you will see those properties are there in your object as they were before. Only thing which is changed is, now you are able to access them because `Admin` type supports them.

[Read this for more detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)